# Datetime Comparing Operation

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have these record in my database :

[image]

the `date` column type in `datetime`

Also i have a query for fetching some records from the table :

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Availibility 
WHERE [date]>= @StartDate AND [date]<=@EndDate
```

And this is screen shot from the result :

[image]

I expected to have Count(*) = 5 but i got 4 !!!
What's my mistake?

**UPDATE**

Changing `SELECT COUNT(*)` to `SELECT *` :

[image]

And these are the latest records :

[image]

Also if i change second from 58 to 56 , i got 5 results!!!

Trying to rebuild of index by this query :

```
alter index all on Availibility rebuild
```

But the results are same and i have 4 records for some seconds.

Comment: It looks like you should be getting 5. Do you have any other conditions? If you run `Select count(*) From Availability` do you get the right number?

Comment: No , i haven't any other conditions , and count(*) has the right number, also if i change start and end times to 2:07:56 and 2:12:56 i get 5 !

Comment: Which 4 rows does it return when you execute `SELECT *`

Comment: It is very interesting result. Can you determine what exactly value is missed?

Comment: @paqogomez the top 5 in the screenshot all fall in the range.

Comment: If this is repeatable and all the information in the question is correct might be a corrupted index.

Comment: @MartinSmith the table hasn't any PK , might be for this?

Comment: `if i change second from 58 to 56` Did you tried 59 seconds or 57? Do you receive correct result on 57 or 59 seconds?

Comment: In case it is a corrupted index as suggested above, try: `alter index all on Availibility rebuild`

Comment: Presumably you get the same if you change to `WHERE [date] between @StartDate AND @EndDate`?

Comment: @JohnLBevan I rebuild index and noting change , i got 4 record for 4 or 5 seconds

Comment: @JohnLBevan Yes , I tried it later, results are same.

Comment: What do you mean by having 4 records for some seconds? Do you get 5 results if you execute the same query with the same parameters a few seconds later?

Comment: This is kind of a long-shot, since it sure looks like it's not, but could it be a rounding error? Try changing your datatype to `DATETIME2(0)` and see if that helps at all.

Comment: @JodyT Yes , exactly for 58,59,60  i get 4 records, but after that i get 5 records correctly.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I Changed the datatype as you said, but no effects on results.

Comment: I've posted some code as an answer - please can you try running this to see if you get the same results / post similar code for the particulars of your case so we can see if it's reproducible elsewhere?

Comment: There is an article that describes some things about datetime http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype/ . Maybe it is a rounding error as noticed @Matthew Haugen

Answer (score 0):

Test Code:

```
create table Availability
(
  [date] datetime not null
)

insert Availability ([date]) select '2014-07-19 02:02:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:03:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:04:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:05:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:06:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:07:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:08:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:09:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:10:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:11:57.000'
union select '2014-07-19 02:12:57.000'

declare @startDate datetime = '2014-07-19 02:07:58.000'
, @endDate datetime = '2014-07-19 02:12:58.000'

select * 
from Availability
where [date] between @startDate and @endDate
```

Comment: Sorry for posting this as an answer - just here to aid discussion in comments / with formatting.  SQL Fiddle not working correctly to use for this purpose.

Comment: I test your code with another database , and its worked correctly, 5 rows returned.this is so interesting...